# What jquery event is triggered when setting an input value with val()?

Tags: jquery

I can setup this listener:

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup paste input change', function() {
  console.log('Hello!');
});
```

If I open **DevTools** and do:

```
$('input[type="text"]').val('a new value');
```

None of the events above are called. Which event should I listen for this cases?

Comment: Why don't you just trigger the callback handler manually by JavaScript?

Comment: `.val()` doesn't trigger any event.

Comment: `$('input[type="text"]').val('a new value').trigger('change');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing an elements value programatically doesn't trigger an event, you'll have to do that yourself. You could use trigger to trigger event handlers in jQuery :

```
$('input[type="text"]').val('a new value').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score -1):

The `.val()` function is designed not to trigger events when executed. What I mean by that is even though it could technically have that functionality due to how jQuery works. If you use the `.val()` function you can manually execute the event you would like using `$(element).val("something").click()/change()/input()/keyup()`

Comment: `The .val() function is designed not to trigger events when executed.` That would imply there is code intentionally written to not trigger an event. That there is no event raised is nothing to do with `.val()` or jQuery at all. Programmatically changing the value using plain JavaScript also won't raise the `change` event.

Comment: I wasn't implying that at all. jQuery however could easily have been designed to implement this functionality. Now I was just stating that it does not do that, and you would need to handle it accordingly. I was specifically referring to jQuery which in its documentation for the `.val()` function does not specifically reference running through event execution or not.