# Have textbox recognize copied input from button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new at this and I tried to search, couldn't find answer.

I have several buttons that have a value assigned to them and when I click them, it copies text into another textbox with a submit button underneath that.

I'm having trouble having the textbox recognize that the value was input into the textbox to therefore enable the submit button.

Sample of what I have:

```
$("#buttonToCopy").click(function () {
    $('#textBox').val("Value").html();
});

$('#textBox').on('input', function () {
    if ($(this).val().length>0);
        $('#submitBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#submitBtn').removeClass('disabled');
    });
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: And your relevant HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be read in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501549/what-jquery-event-is-triggered-when-setting-an-input-value-with-val), jQuery doesn't fire events when using the .val() method. This means that your code

```
$("#buttonToCopy").click(function () {
    $('#textBox').val("Value").html();
});
```

will not fire "input", or "change" events. You could trigger the event yourself:

```
$("#buttonToCopy").click(function () {
    $('#textBox').val("Value").html();
    $('#textBox').trigger('input');
});
```

Alternatively, you could easily call the function to disable the button from the buttonToCopy as well:

```
$("#buttonToCopy").click(function () {
    $('#textBox').val("Value").html();
    EnableSubmitButton()
});

$('#textBox').on('input', function () {
    EnableSubmitButton()
});

function EnableSubmitButton(){
   if ($(this).val().length>0) {
      $('#submitBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('#submitBtn').removeClass('disabled');
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @WeSt for the reference and the answer!